# How to set custom port for DNS in systemd-resolved

Tags: systemd, internal-dns

I want to add local DNS server with port 8600 to systemd-resolved for request forwarding.
I've tried to change /etc/systemd/resolved.conf like this

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.1#8600
```

but this is not counts as a port (btw, : didn't works too)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`systemd-resolved` is not really known for it's full-featured configuration options! But I think with a bit of `iptables` magic, you can get it to work with.
First do something like this:

```
[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.52 #instead of 127.0.0.53 which is systemd-resolved itself.
```

You can of course choose any other number between 2-255. Just don't use 53 itself.

Then you have to redirect any packets headed for `127.0.0.1:53` to `127.0.0.52:53` with `iptables`. Here is my best untested attempt: *(I don't have your environment to test this, correct me if I'm wrong)*

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-destination 127.0.0.52 --to-ports 53
```

and finally you should probably make this config persistent on reboots. `iptables-persistent` might help.

*Some Helpful links:*

- [Changing resolve.conf might be tricky.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/516808/194092)
- [Persistent rules can also be tricky.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/125841/194092)

Comment: I got this to work by changing the iptables rules a bit:

```iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.52 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8600```
and
```iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.52 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8600```

Answer (score 0):

you may simply specify the port(works with DoT at least):

```
[Resolve]
DNS=<ip>:<port>#<domain>
DNSOverTLS=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem based on Keith Langmead's answer here: [Link](https://superuser.com/questions/1806255/how-to-configure-centos-against-new-dns-server-and-port)

The `/etc/resolv.conf` config file doesn't support any form of alternative port number, so will only connect natively via port 53.

The only way to achieve what you're looking for is to have something in the middle to take the port 53 request from the client, change it to use another port and then deliver that request to the server.

The way others have achieved that is to use iptables to reroute that internal request as needed. An example:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8600
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p udp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:8600
```

You can simply use different IPs instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: Note that systemd resolved  and  `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` is not `/etc/resolv.conf` - The current version of resolved does support a port specification https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/resolved.conf.html#DNS=

Comment: @HBruijn  you're right. many many thanks.